# What is the fastest way to select data with LINQ by keys collection?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

There is the following issue:
you have an

```
IEnumerable<TClass> collection
```

where TClass looks like this

```
public TClass
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Also you have an

```
IEnumerable<Guid> ids
```

that contains ids if needed TClass objects. You know for sure that **collection** contains TClass objects with ids were given.

I know two ways to get TClass objects by an ids collection:

1)

```
var result = collection.Where(x => ids.Any(id => x.Id.Equals(id)));
```

2)

```
var result = collection.Join(ids, x => x.Id, id => id, (x, id) => x);
```

So what is the best practice and the fastest way to get a TClass collection by an ids collection? Maybe you know an another way?

Comment: [Race your horses!](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Don't ask which is more performant. Try it out.

Comment: Where uses less memory, but may take longer.  The time a join will take can vary depending on amount of data in database and amount of memory in computer.  Once you use up all the memory in machine you start putting data into swap space which is very slow.